# Is raise really a keyword?

Tags: python, function, object, oop, exception

Take these examples:

```py
>>> raise(BaseException())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
BaseException

>>> raise BaseException()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
BaseException
```

Recall this aphorism:

> [There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

If `raise` is a keyword, why is it syntactically allowed to be viewed as being invoked like a function?

There are some other keywords as well which allow attached parenthesis.
Isn't it confusing?

Comment: You just put `BaseException` in parentheses, which does nothing - it just allows you to skip the space after `raise`. You can do the same with `if(True):` or whatever. Just please don't.

Comment: Yes, `raise` is really a keyword. You can answer this by reading the documentation. It *is not* "invoked like a function", and writing parentheses there *does not* make it thus. The way you know that `raise` is a keyword is that you *may also* write the statement *without* parentheses. In fact, you have already done so in your example. Voting to close as not reproducible, because this is a question asking for an explanation of something that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Consider: I can write `-(3)` and get back `-3`. Is unary minus a function? No.

Answer (score 2):

Putting parentheses around something just makes it a parenthesized value; it does not magically make it a function call.

`1` is the same as `(1)`, therefore `return 1` is the same as `return (1)`.

But it's not a function call.

Comment: I assumed there is an unwritten rule of separating keywords from the upcoming texts. And when an identifier is attached to parentheses, its being called.

Answer (score 1):

You can add parentheses around any expression, it’s just that the parentheses are required for function calls.

```
print 123 # error
print(123) # ok
print((123)) # extra parentheses ok
```

And

```
raise BaseException() # ok
raise (BaseException()) # extra parentheses ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bare parenthesis would do nothing to the element.

Therefore there is no difference between with and without parenthesis:

```
>>> (BaseException())
BaseException()
>>> BaseException()
BaseException()
>>>
```

Only if you add a comma would make it a tuple.

So in short:

#### `raise` is a keyword!

Answer (score 0):

It's not being invoked as a function, you simply have extra parenthesis around the exception object.  Consider:

```
ex = (BaseException())
raise ex
```

Additionally, your second example provides a counterargument.  If `raise` was not a keyword, that example would fail.

Comment: The second example reminded me of `print "something"` in python 2.x

Comment: Yes, in 2.x, `print` was a keyword. Now it isn't.